# Deployment error since Catalina update - zsh: /usr/local/bin/cap: bad interpreter... no such file or directory

Tags: ruby, macos, deployment, macos-catalina, cap

Since updating to Catalina, I'm having some real issues deploying all my sites.
This if the first issue.

When I want to push my local site to uat (staging), I run `cap uat deploy branch=release/4.0.0` and it usually (before the update) runs and pushes all my changes to my uat site.

Instead, I'm getting the following error, and no matter what I try, I can't seem to get rid of it:

`zsh: /usr/local/bin/cap: bad interpreter: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: no such file or directory`

I've spent way too long trying to suss this out and I couldn't really do with some guidance.
If anyone can help, I'd be so thankful!

UPDATE:

The deploy now runs, however it fails and I now have the following error:

```
...

(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
TypeError: no _dump_data is defined for class Enumerator

Tasks: TOP => rsync:create_release => rsync:release
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: no _dump_data is defined for class Enumerator

** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:

INFO [48d8ce56] Finished in 0.110 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

DEBUG [5fe5c207] Running [ -f /home/xxxx/capistrano_uat/shared/.htaccess ] as xxxx@xxx.xxx.xx.xx

DEBUG [5fe5c207] Command: [ -f /home/xxxx/capistrano_uat/shared/.htaccess ]

DEBUG [5fe5c207] Finished in 0.110 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

DEBUG [91d12373] Running [ -f /home/xxxx/capistrano_uat/shared/wp-config.php ] as xxxx@185.xxx.xx.xx

DEBUG [91d12373] Command: [ -f /home/xxxx/capistrano_uat/shared/wp-config.php ]

DEBUG [91d12373] Finished in 0.110 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

DEBUG [eed79024] Running [ -f /home/xxxx/capistrano_uat/shared/awards-winner.png ] as xxxx@xxx.xxx.xx.xx

DEBUG [eed79024] Command: [ -f /home/xxxx/capistrano_uat/shared/awards-winner.png ]

DEBUG [eed79024] Finished in 0.109 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

DEBUG [8bb292a4] Running [ -f /home/xxxx/capistrano_uat/shared/rar-recommended.png ] as xxxx@xxx.xxx.xx.xx

DEBUG [8bb292a4] Command: [ -f /home/xxxx/capistrano_uat/shared/rar-recommended.png ]

DEBUG [8bb292a4] Finished in 0.110 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

DEBUG [134b2ada] Running [ -f /home/xxxx/capistrano_uat/current/REVISION ] as xxxx@xxx.xxx.xx.xx

DEBUG [134b2ada] Command: [ -f /home/xxxx/capistrano_uat/current/REVISION ]

DEBUG [134b2ada] Finished in 0.109 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

DEBUG [b142445e] Running /usr/bin/env cat /home/xxxx/capistrano_uat/current/REVISION 2>/dev/null as xxxx@xxx.xxx.xx.xx

DEBUG [b142445e] Command: /usr/bin/env cat /home/xxxx/capistrano_uat/current/REVISION 2>/dev/null

DEBUG [b142445e]     a61943df88d68ca6309b1886c140d86bad68ac59

DEBUG [b142445e] Finished in 0.116 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

Comment: seems like a related issue with this https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15460

i haven't upgraded to catalina yet, but seeing you used the system ruby, I would like to suggest using rvm or rbenv

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a little new to all this, especially these errors and I'm a little unsure of where to start. What to do?

Comment: I've tried a combination of this things (on the linked article), but it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: try reinstall your gem using `bundle install` if you use bundler or `gem install capistrano -v <version>` if you install it directly using gem command before. If you haven't done xcode update, try updating it and redo the above step, hopefully it will your issue since it solved my issue after mac OS upgrade before. If all thing fail, you can try installing ruby using rvm and install your gem on ruby provided by rvm instead of using system one (remember to match your ruby version used for development to avoid issue)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ran all of the above and the deploy is still failing.
I'm now getting the following: 

`(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
TypeError: no _dump_data is defined for class Enumerator

Tasks: TOP => rsync:create_release => rsync:release
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: no _dump_data is defined for class Enumerator
`

Comment: I have no idea how to fix it then, sorry. Last time I had that issue with different gem can be fixed by reinstalling ruby (in my case I use rvm). I hope others can help you find the other solution.

Comment: Thanks anyway for all your help.